# oracle greatest function working correctly?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have doubt in the greatest function : regarding the second case,is that result actually correct? [image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. Look at the exponents: the first number is notated `-E08`, the second `-E09`. The negative sign indicates these are decimals, the digits how many decimal places to the move the decimal point.  So the second number is an order of magnitude smaller than the first.